# Растянуть по ширине картинку загружаемую с помощью Glide

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, glide

Когда ресурс для ImageView вставлен статичный то все нормально работает, картинка растягивается по ширине, но когда загружаю картинку с интернет не работает layout_width="fill_parent". Как мне решить эту проблему?

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:elevation="2dp"
                   />
```

Для загрузки картинки использую Glide

```
Glide.with(this).load(SharedPrefManager.getmInstance(this).getPICS()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).placeholder(R.drawable.logo5).into(imagine);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fill_parent - deprecated -> Используй match_parent

У ImageView можно задать

- scaleType="centerCrop" - Картинка обрежется под необходимый размер
- Или scaleType="fitXY" -  Картинка растянется, чаще непропорционально

Подробнее про scaleType:
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/imageview.php#scaletype

Comment: Спасибо помог scaleType="centerCrop" у меня было scaleType="fitCenter"

Answer (score 0):

Можете добавить `fitCenter()` в Glide

```
Glide.with(this).load(SharedPrefManager.getmInstance(this).getPICS()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).placeholder(R.drawable.logo5).fitCenter().into(imagine);
```

Comment: увы не работает